# PHP - Generating correct SOAP data for Salesforce API

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

Can anyone help point me in the correct direction to generate valid XML to use with the Salesforce API. I normally avoid SOAP like the plague but have no choice here and it seems like I'm at the bottom of a vertical learning curve.

I've got a full WSDL which as far as I'm aware should cover every part of the request, including all the appropriate namespaces and complex types, but I just can't generate a request that matches their example.

A subset of the example request looks like the following -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPI" xmlns:web1="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPIUtils">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <web:SessionHeader>
         <web:sessionId> SESSION_ID_FROM_LOGIN_METHOD </web:sessionId>
      </web:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:upsertLeadOrUpdateAccount>
       <web:leadFromWebsite>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <web1:salesforceId></web1:salesforceId>
            ...
```

By calling the relevant method I can get an `<ns1:upsertLeadOrUpdateAccount>` request (not the same namespace id but that doesn't really matter), with an empty `<leadFromWebsite>` element. However, I just can't work out how to get the `<salesforceId>` sub element in there with the correct namespace. Everything I do either seems to do nothing, or adds an "xsi-type" attribute to the parent rather than using the namespace prefix.

The closest I've got is the following, which adds the namespace to the root element, but seems to create a weird looking `xsi-type="ns1:web1"` attribute, rather than just prefixing all the elements with `web1`.

I do have complexTypes for everything in the WSDL so I'm sure there should be a way for the SOAP library to handle all the heavy lifting for me. I really don't want to resort to just generating the whole lot by hand.

```
$data = new stdclass();
$data->salesforceId = '123';

$args = [

    'leadFromWebsite' => new SoapVar($data, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'web1', 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPIUtils')
];
```

Output -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPIUtils" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPI">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:SessionHeader>
      <ns2:sessionId>123</ns2:sessionId>
    </ns2:SessionHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:upsertLeadOrUpdateAccount>
      <ns2:leadFromWebsite xsi:type="ns1:web1">
        <salesforceId>123</salesforceId>
      </ns2:leadFromWebsite>
    </ns2:upsertLeadOrUpdateAccount>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: You don't need SOAP this. Salesforce provides REST APIs for most operations on standard objects, upserting leads or contacts is certainly possible via REST. See [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) for more info

Comment: @identigral I've been given documentation from a 3rd party Salesforce integrator that includes several methods that have either been created specifically for this customer, or extended, and for reasons I'm not sure of, some of them are documented as SOAP and some REST. (Even the REST ones specify a sessionId is required, and refer me back to the SOAP login method).

Comment: @identigral Of course looking back, it would make sense for Salesforce to design their integration to always allow either. However I don't know whether the 3rd party have somehow implemented their changes in a way that only work with the method they show. (I would of expected their documentation to specify either method is available if it was, rather than showing some as SOAP and some as REST). Either way it doesn't really matter now as I appear to have it working.

Comment: @identigral Thanks for your comment though, made me think that I may have been better off asking the 3rd party integrator directly if they were able to provide all the applicable calls via REST. I'm sure SOAP is very useful in enterprise, but it lost the 'Simple' part a long time ago.. Seems SOAP these days pretty much relies on using tools to automate it. Just the WSDL for the Salesforce login is over 5000 lines of XML.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this fully with the salesforce API yet, but I think I've managed to generate XML that looks correct - at least a lot closer than I was.

Seems my main issue was confusing type and node namespaces. I wanted to specify the namespace for the node, not the data type.

The following code generates xml that is much closer to the example requests -

```
$data = [];
$data[] = new SoapVar('123', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'salesforceId', 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPIUtils');

$args = [
    'leadFromWebsite' => new SoapVar($data, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'leadFromWebsite', 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPI')
];

$s->upsertLeadOrUpdateAccount($args);
```

XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPIUtils" 
  xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebsiteAPI">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:SessionHeader>
      <ns2:sessionId>123</ns2:sessionId>
    </ns2:SessionHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:upsertLeadOrUpdateAccount>
      <ns2:leadFromWebsite>
        <ns1:salesforceId>123</ns1:salesforceId>
      </ns2:leadFromWebsite>
    </ns2:upsertLeadOrUpdateAccount>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```